# Substring from reverse in PostgreSql

Tags: sql, postgresql

How do we substring from reverse in Postgres? In oracle we can provide the no.of occurrences of the pattern and extract the expected records. In Postgres we do not have such option.
I tried using `substring(), left() and right()` functions, still it is not working. Any suggestion would be helpful.

Value in the column,

```
col1
100~500~~~~Bangalore~~~~KA~null~Train
```

Expected result,

```
Train
```

Comment: Do you want the string after the last `~`? Or the string between the (n)th and the (n+1)th occurrence of `~`?

Answer (score 3):

To get the characters after the last `~` you can use `substring()` with a regex:

```
substring(col1 from '~([^~]+)$')
```

Or get the position of the last `~` by using the reverse function:

```
right(col1, strpos(reverse(col1), '~') - 1)
```

A more general approach is to convert the string to an array, then pick the last array element:

```
(string_to_array(col1, '~'))[cardinality(string_to_array(col1, '~'))]
```

---

The best solution to this sort of problems is to not store multiple values delimited by some character in a single column. If you really need to de-normalize using arrays or JSON would at least be a bit more flexible (and robust)